# How to do a proper left join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This should be a really simple problem to solve, but for some reason Entity Framework makes it really hard for me. I just need to do a simple left join...

I have two tables. For example, a user table:

```
user_id | name | fk_group_id
```

And a group table

```
group_id | groupname
```

In raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN groups AS g
ON u.fk_group_id = g.group_id
WHERE groupname = 'my group'
```

Super easy in SQL. But when i search for answers on how to do this is Entity Framework, then there's one thing that immidiately goes through my mind... WTF...!?!?
Super large constructed, weird formatted "queries" are performed and i'm really confused what i need and what not...

So i'm hoping someone could help me with my specific problem. How would one rewrite the above SQL query in (LINQ?) Entity Framework.

Currently i have this:

```
var bla = (from m in myEnt.Users
          // My join attempt..
          join mp in myEnt.Groups on m equals mp.group_id into n
          where n.group_name == "something"
          select m);
```

Even if this was working, i really don't see how this is suppose to make my life easier.. Oo

Anyway, i really hope someone can help me out :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm, you don't have to explicitly do that with any ORM. That's the catch here, that's what mapping's for.

You can just go:

```
var blah = myEnt.Users.Where(user => user.Group.Name == "something");
```

Or in the alternate syntax

```
from usr in myEnt.Users
where usr.Group.Name == "something"
select usr`
```

If it's many-to-one relationship after mapping to objects, then every `User` entity will have the navigation property to his  `Group`, and every `Group` will have a `User` collection. Then you only have to filter the results appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, that does make more sense to me and actually makes things easier :-) Although i have one more question about this. I tried to explicitly tell what kind of type "var bla" needs to be, so: **ddUsers bla = (query...)** --- But it says: **Cannot convert IQueryable<ddUsers> to target type ddUsers** It does work however when i simply put **var** infront of it. Does this mean i can't explicitly tell what type the query is returning?

Comment: @w00 Well, `ddUsers` is a single 'row' in database terms, a single entity. `Where` always returns a collection, so `IQueryable<ddUsers>`. If you want only single entity, and you know it's in the database, you can use `ddUser blah = myEnt.Users.Single(user => user.Group.Name == "something")` (this will return single entity or throw an exception if there's more than one match or if the selection was empty), or `First` to get the first one, `Last` to get the last etc. :)

Comment: I actually don't need a single entity. But you made me remeber that i forgot to put a IEnumerable<ddUsers> infront of it :-) --- It's working the way i want it now. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

why do you need a join?
isn't there a relation between users and groups already?

```
var bla = from m in myEnt.Users
           where m.Group.Groupname = "something"
           select m;
```

this should do just fine or am i wrong?